# How to add several string together such as "123"+"456"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, string-concatenation, stdstring, string-literals

How to achieve such operation, the Visual Studio always tells me that it was wrong.
The wrong code is `C2110` and `E2140`.
Can anyone help?

```
std::string a = "2323" + "22323" + "232332";
```

Comment: Try `std::string("2323") + "22323"`

Comment: `std::string a = "2323" "22323" "232332";`. String literals separated only by whitespace get concatenated.

Comment: `string a="2323" "22323" "232332";` should work

Comment: To elaborate on the 'problem', the `+` operator is only defined for an `std::string`, however `"2323"` (without any prefix) is not an `std::string`, it is a `const char *`. So you need to explicitely declare the first argument as `std::string` to make `+ (const char *)` available.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium — `”2323”` without any prefix is not a `const char*`. It is an array of 5 `const char`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Which, if you were to save them into a variable, would 'decay' into a `const char *`, yes.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium -- maybe, depending on the type of the variable. But that has nothing to do with the type of a string literal, which is an array. Full stop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `"2323"` is not a `std::string`, it is a `const char[5]`.

Since C++14, you *can* have a literal of type `std::string`:

```
using namespace std::string_literals;

std::string a = "2323"s + "22323"s + "232332"s;
```

Comment: `"2323"s + "22323" + "232332"` would suffice. You don't need three `std::string`s.

Answer (score 2):

In this declaration

```
std::string a="2323" + "22323" + "232332";
```

you are using an expression with string literals and the operator + that is not defined for character arrays and correspondingly for pointers to which the string literals are implicitly converted.

You could write for example

```
std::string a = "2323"s + "22323" + "232332";
```

using the user-defined string literal `"2323"s`  or you could write

```
std::string a = std::string( "2323" ) + "22323" + "232332";
```

Another way is to declare the object `a` like

```
std::string a;
```

and then write

```
a += "2323";
a += "22323";
a += "232332";
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    {
        using namespace std::literals;
        
        std::string a = "2323"s + "22323" + "232332";
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
    
    {
        std::string a = std::string( "2323" ) + "22323" + "232332";
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
    
    {
        std::string a;
        
        a += "2323";
        a += "22323";
        a += "232332";
        
        std::cout << a << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
232322323232332
232322323232332
232322323232332
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined `operator+` for `const char[X]` (a const array of char, with X the number of characters in it; e.g. `const char[5]`  is the type of a literal `"2323"` as in your code) - nor for `const char *`, to which they could be automatically converted. That's why C++ compilers will not let you do this.
However, there is an [`operator+` for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator+). Since this operator in turn returns a string, you can chain-call, that is, call the + operator again on its result.
So you can write something like this:

```
std::string a = std::string("2323") + "22323" + "232332";
```

In case you are already using C++14 or later, you can use literals of type string via an `s` suffix, then an alternate form of writing this would be

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
std::string a = "2323"s + "22323" + "232332";
```

If it is just multiple `const char[X]` literals that you want to concatenate, you can also just write them one after the other, like this:

```
std::string a("2323" "22323" "232332");
// or:
std::string a = "2323" "22323" "232332";
```

The compiler will automatically concatenate them for you.

Comment: They are char arrays, not char pointers. You wouldn't be able to concatenate pointers like that.

Comment: missed that nuance, thanks for the hint, should be correct now?

Comment: Thank you for fixing. Seems fine now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers provided, you can also use the `std::stringstream` to build up an `std::string`.

```
#include <sstream>

int main( )
{
    std::stringstream ss{ };
    ss << "2323" << "22323" << "232332";

   // Maybe you also want to conditionally append something else.
   if ( some_condition )
   {
       // Note that I'm inserting an integer here.
       ss << 42;
   }

   // When you're ready you can call the str( ) member function
   // to attain a copy of the underlying string.
   std::string s{ ss.str( ) };
}
```